# .net Regex.Replace only within a specified capture group

Tags: .net, regex

Is it possible to use the .net Regex class to do a replace on a specific capture group.

for example

```
<customer.*?(display="(?:yes|no)")?.*?>
```

I want to match on the Customer xml element but replace within the display attribute capture group. i think that would be group 1, but i could always name this.

Comment: Why don't you use an xml parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to capture the stuff that comes before and after the display attribute.

```
(<customer.*?)(display="(?:yes|no)")(.*?>)
```

You can then use that in your replace lambda

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(<customer.*?)(display=""(?:yes|no)"")(.*?>)", m => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", m.Groups[1], /* replacement string based on m.Groups[2] */, m.Groups[3]));
```

Comment: Agreed, but you need to get rid of that third `?`.  In the original regex it made the capturing group optional, which was wrong to begin with.  (It would never capture anything, whether the `display` attribute was present or not.)  Where you've got it, it's a syntax error.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Oops, thanks for the catch.  I wasn't paying attention.  Fixed now.

Comment: My actual answer was a bit different but i'll give you the credit for the idea, see my answer for how i implemented it, i did it in a way that you didn't need the pre and post groups

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andrews answer i have extended this a bit by creating a method to handle the replacement. In my situation i wanted to replace a whole group so i created a helper class to do this. Also it does not require you to create a pre and post capture group to achieve this.

```
/// <summary>
/// A Regular Expression match and replace class
/// </summary>
public class RegexReplacer
{
    private readonly int _captureGroupToReplace;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises the RegEx replacer with matching criteria.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">A name that identifies this replacement pattern</param>
    /// <param name="matchCriteria">A regular Expression used to locate the values to replace</param>
    /// <param name="replacementValue">The value that will replace the matched pattern</param>
    /// <param name="captureGroupToReplace">The Capture group that should be replaced. The default is the entire match</param>
    public RegexReplacer(string name, Regex matchCriteria, string replacementValue, int captureGroupToReplace = 0)
    {
        _captureGroupToReplace = captureGroupToReplace;
        Name = name;
        ReplacementValue = replacementValue;
        MatchCriteria = matchCriteria;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Regex MatchCriteria { get; set; }

    public string ReplacementValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds and replaces all instances of a string within the supplied string or replaces a group if the group id is supplied in the constructor
    /// </summary>
    public string ReplaceInString(string stringToSearch)
    {
        if (_captureGroupToReplace != 0)
            return MatchCriteria.Replace(stringToSearch, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceGroup));

        return MatchCriteria.Replace(stringToSearch, ReplacementValue);
    }

    private string ReplaceGroup(Match match)
    {
        try
        {
            var matchedString = match.Value;
            //Match index is based on the original string not the matched string
            int groupIndex = match.Groups[_captureGroupToReplace].Index - match.Index;
            int groupLength = match.Groups[_captureGroupToReplace].Length;

            var preGroupString = matchedString.Substring(0, groupIndex);
            var postGroupString = matchedString.Substring(groupIndex + groupLength, matchedString.Length - (groupIndex + groupLength));

            var replacedString = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", preGroupString, ReplacementValue, postGroupString);

            return replacedString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return match.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I also had to modify my original pattern so it would give me an empty group at the end of the xml to insert an attribute if it didn't exist the usage looks like

```
var replacer = new RegexReplacer("DisplayCustomerAttribute",
                 new Regex(@"(?:<customer\s.*?((\sdisplay=""(?:yes|no)"").*?|())>)"),
                 @" display=""yes""", 1)
 xmlString = replacer.ReplaceInString(xmlString);
```

As a side note the reason for this is because the .net xml serialization does not include an attribute when the value is the same as the default. This is ok when your in control of the consumer but in our case we are not so we need to be explicit.